# C# Cannot convert type 'String' to 'AreaCal.VolumeSphere'

Tags: c#, mono, readline

I am new to C# and trying to make a volume cal that allows you to choose the shape you want to find the volume of I am trying to do that with read line. I am getting Cannot convert type 'String' to 'AreaCal.VolumeSphere' at the read line in static void main

```
using System;

namespace AreaCal
{

    class VolumeSphere
    {
        double pi = 3.14159265359;
        double ft = 1.333333333333333333333333333333333333;
        double r;
        public void Details()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Volume of a Circle");
            Console.WriteLine ("Type Radius");
            r = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        }
        public double GetVolume()
        {
            return ft * pi * r * r * r;
        }
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Volume: {0}", GetVolume());
        }

    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            VolumeSphere Sphere = new VolumeSphere ();
            Sphere = (Console.ReadLine ());
            if (Sphere != null)
                Console.WriteLine ("awwww");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this line: `Sphere = (Console.ReadLine ());`. `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`. So you can't assign an object of type `VolumeSphere` to a `string`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to make a selection system so the user can type a string and have the volume calculator they requested ran. I only have one Cal right now its volume of a sphere.

Comment: You're going to need to flush this program out way more than what you have here first. At the very least, come up with psuedocode for what you want the program to do. We can't guess the flow of the program for you.

Comment: You are not doing any selection, only assigning your keyboard input directly to your VolumeSphere variable, you need to use a Switch statement to determine which calculator that you want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reading your question you mention that you are trying to select multiple calculators, in your example you are trying to assign your keyboard input to your VolumeSphere Object. Here is a quick and dirty implementation of a menu for your calculator, you can play with it and expand it to meet your needs.

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value;
        bool run;

        run = true;
        while(run)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Compute Volume of a Sphere");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Compute Something else");
            Console.WriteLine("etc,etc,etc");

            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case 1:
                        VolumeSphere Sphere = new VolumeSphere();
                        Sphere.Details();
                        Console.WriteLine(Sphere.GetVolume());
                        Sphere.Display();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("GoodBye");
                        run = false;
                        break;

                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sphere` is an object of class `VolumeSphere` but you are assigning a string `Console.ReadLine` here that is wrong. Probably you wanted to do something like:

```
VolumeSphere Sphere = new VolumeSphere();
Sphere.Details();
Sphere.Display();
```

But your requirement is not clear. So please provide more details on it. And also consider using constructor to pass radius value to your `VolumeSphere` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
VolumeSphere Sphere = new VolumeSphere();
Sphere = (Console.ReadLine ());
```

This is throwing the error.  Console.Readline() returns a string read in from standard input.    You are trying to assign this to the variable Sphere, which you declared to be of type VolumeSphere.  I am not sure what you are reading from standard input, but I assume it is radius.

You need to do this instead;

```
string radius = Console.ReadLine();
VolumeSphere Sphere = new VolumeSphere(Convert.ToDouble(radius));
```

This passes the string parameter converted to a double to the VolumeSphere constructor, which you are going to define like this inside of class VolumeSphere:

```
public VolumeSphere(double r)
{
   this.r = r;
}
```

You should also remove the Details method and put its writelines in the main before you read your input because it is better to encapsulate your models and user interface.